# Loading PHP MongoDB class with XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, mongodb, dll

Okay.
I'm trying to use MongoDB with Node.js and PHP/XAMPP on Windows 7, but I can't seem to install the PHP MongoClient Class at all.

I am a complete beginner with MongoDB and I have to say that if I wasn't committed to solving this I'd have given up by now.
 After lots of fiddling around trying to install the correct device driver version etc., I have come across yet another problem. But first, let me explain the steps I have taken so far.

Installed XAMPP v3.2.1, keeping all defaults.
Looked at phpinfo() on localhost:

`PHP Version: 5.5.15. PHP Architecture: x86. Thread-Safe: Enabled`.

Figured out where to download the software, as well as the correct version, etc.

Went to *pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.5/windows/*.

At "DLL List" (PHP 5.5), I selected: `5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x86.

Went to PHP.ini (not the development or production version, but the actual one), and added 1 line: `extension=php_mongo.dll`. (line 887). No semicolon in front.

Started Apache.

Error: PHP Startup: `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll` could not be found on your computer.

I found out that when you manually type the file extension of a program that is already saved as a specific type, my computer simply prepends it to the existing one. The program was saved with the extension dll.dll. I got rid of that.

Restarted Apache.

Then I got this... Error: PHP Startup: `Libsasl.dll` is not found on your computer. Unable to load dynamic library `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll`. Try reinstalling the program.

I reinstalled the program. As I suspected, no missing file was magically created.

I then looked online to try to find this 'dll' file. After some searching, I was able to install `Libsasl.dll` via *dll-files.com*.

I restarted Apache.

Next problem:

Error: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll` - Access is denied.

I tried running XAMPP as an administrator. Same result.

The program is definitely there, but I can't seem to access it for whatever reason.

Why? I am getting quite frustrated with this and I would love everything to start working properly.
I have a hunch that it has something to do with read/write privileges but I don't know where to look.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, then after adding the path of the ".dll" file's folder to the environment variable as a system variable path, it worked. It is then able to find the file. At the end that was the only step which was stopping xampp to load the ".dll" file, although it was present in that folder. Often people miss this step as it is no where pointed out clearly.